# php Процедурный на ООП

Tags: php, ооп, procedure

Есть несколько веб приложений, написанные на процедурном php, недавно задался вопросом, стоит ли переписывать их с процедурного на ООП ?
Слышал, что

1. ООП более удобочитаемый
2. более удобный для расширения программы

Но также слышал что ООП в php реализован послабее процедурного.

Comment: Если программа работает хорошо и справляется со своими задачами то просто нет смысла.

Comment: ну это понятно )

Comment: На PHP можно даже и в функциональном стиле писать. Все зависит от задач, знаний и собственных предпочтений.

Comment: Зависит от того - насколько сильно эти веб-приложения будут изменяться в дальнейшем. Сильно - пересаживаем на фреймворк+ORM , слабо - ничего не делаем, средненько - вводим ооп постепенно, добавляем классы по чуть-чуть.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Определенно стоит.
Первое. ООП действительно позволяет расширять программе свой функционал без надобности переписывать 100 миллионов строк.
Второе. Написав класс один раз, ты сможешь использовать его во всех своих будущих проектах. 
Ну и третье. Код смотрится красиво и занимает куда меньше места нежели написанный в процедурном.

P.S. Осторожно! Есть большая вероятность, начав писать в ОО-стиле, больше не вернуться к процедурному. :-)

Comment: Минус по нескольким причинам: 1. если работает зачем его переписывать. 2. Мы незнаем какие именно задачи решает код, может в процедурном стиле он выглядит более читаемы (локаничным). 3. Не стоит переусложнять логику лепить патерны и др. примудрости к hello world.

Comment: 1. Потому что удобнее расширять и редактировать в будущем. 2. Возможно и так, хотя я не видел еще код, который выглядеть в процедурном стиле лаконичнее нежели чем в ОО. 3. Вы слишком все упрощаете сводя все к нативному Hello world.

Comment: в коде больше 300 строк , hello world врядли назовешь)

Comment: @S1lllver главное минус лупануть было, а потом свести все к тому что это автор виноват из-за того не сказал, что у него там код не <?= 'Hello world'; ?> Все нормально, здесь так принято. :D

Comment: @Dmitry Potter правильно минус, но больше опускать не буду. Правильно - потому что пост начинается с "Определенно стоит" - как можно утверждать это, зная про проекты только "несколько веб приложений, написанные на процедурном php" . А "ООП действительно позволяет расширять программе свой функционал без надобности переписывать 100 миллионов" - так процедурно-функциональный стиль тоже это позволяет)

Comment: Слово "несколько" уже говорит о том, что там далеко не Hello world. Чтобы в будущем проще разработки вести и создают библиотеки для себя, которые используют в дальнейшем. Я не видел еще мазахистов, кроме вас, которые чтоб не писать на ОО пишут чисто на функциях для процедурного стиля. Что такое процедурно-функциональный стиль? Есть процедурный и ОО стили. Все. Чтоб понять меня, ответьте на такой вопрос для СЕБЯ: процедурный стиль существует без функций? А ОО? Вот то-то и оно.

Comment: @Dmitry Potter причём здесь Hello word. Я ничего про мой стиль не говорил, не переходите на личности, и не несите чушь) Переписывать что-то стоит только тогда, когда в этом есть смысл. Если немалый проект приносит 1 мил. руб/мес, и написан исключительно в процедурном стиле и радикальных улучшений не предвидится - его НЕ надо переписывать, это вам скажет любой. И учите матчасть https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр переписывать придется рано или поздно все (или почти все) для того, чтобы при смене программистов было проще поддерживать старый код. А так же пользоваться классами, которые использованы в разработке этого псевдо-проекта с прибылью в млн. рублей в месяц в других проектах, которые тоже будут приносить еще по миллиону каждый... При чем тут матчасть вообще? Есть два вида программистов: которые пишут в оо-стиле и те, которые пишут в процедурном. Закончим обсуждение на этом.

Answer (score 1):

Определите "процедурный стиль", пожалуйста.

- если весь ваш код - это гора функций, которые вызывают другие функции, в C-стиле - и это работает - пусть работает.
- другое дело, что без использования статических методов классов / пространств имен есть риск начать писать функции с дурацкими именами, в духе `billingGetData` и `ftpServiceGetData` вместо `billing::getData`
- если вы соберетесь куски вашего кода использовать в разных других проектах - возможно, у вас возникнут проблемы из-за того, что имена ваших функций будут пересекаться с чужими (и, в примере выше - даже вашими собственными) функциями.
- Но: предыдущее замечание справедливо только для кода, который не использует пространства имен (namespace).

Одна из забавных причин использования ООП в PHP - а именно - ограничение видимости функций с одинаковыми именами - реализуется при помощи двух механизмов - пространства имен и статические методы классов (вспомним Python и его модули, кстати)

Используя пространства имен или статические методы классов вы можете спокойно кодить в процедурном стиле, я видел большие кодовые базы, которые вполне хорошо живут долгие годы.

- другое дело, что ООП, например, позволяет использовать конструкторы и деструкторы, спасая кодера от ошибок в духе "я забыл вызвать функцию инициализации" и "я забыл вызвать деструктор и закрыть файлы"
- Но: предыдущее замечание перекрывается тем, что современная модель разработки PHP практически не использует долгоживущих процессов, поэтому деструкторы ему не нужны. Запрос пришел, скрипт запустился, запрос ушел, скрипт умер, все закрылось.
- Если вы соберетесь выдавать ваши разработки в opensource или с вашим кодом будут работать много программистов, привыкших к ООП-модели работы - переводите код на ООП, поддержка ООП на PHP  находится на вполне высоком уровне с 5 версии

В итоге: It depends. Зависит от количества и качества кода, сколько проблем он вам причиняет, можно ли его запихнуть в микросервис и забыть навсегда, есть ли у вас время на переписывание, достаточно ли ваш код универсален, чтобы переиспользовать его в других проектах.

Comment: проблемы именования вряд ли относятся к ооп

Comment: почти не относятся, но многие используют ооп для того, чтобы продолжать кодить в процедурном стиле, используя классы как пространства имен. Даже не скажу, хорошо это или плохо - "это php", впрочем, проапдейтил

Comment: @strangeqargo "это пхп" - не, пхп может позволять кодить в хороших ООП традициях. Но за ответ плюс, по делу написано.